# Java - How do I code optional regex patterns with a matcher

Tags: java, regex

Let’s say I am looping through a text file and come across the following two strings with random words and integer values

```
“foo 11 25”
“foo 38 15 976 24”
```

I write a regex pattern that would match both strings, for example:

```
((?:[a-z][a-z]+)\\s+\\d+\\s\\d+)
```

But, the problem is I don’t think this regex would allow me to get to all 4 integer values in the 2nd string.

Q1.) How can I create a single pattern that leaves these 3rd and 4th integers optional?

Q2.) How do I write the matcher code to only go after the 3rd and 4th values when they are found by the pattern?

Here is a template program to help anyone willing to offer a hand.  Thanks.

```
public void foo(String fooFile) {
        //Assume fooFile contains the two strings
        //"foo 11 25";
        //"foo 38 976 24";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((?:[a-z][a-z]+)\\s+\\d+\\s\\d+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        BufferedReader br  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fooFile));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            //Process the patterns
            Matcher m1 = p.matcher(line);
            if (m1.find()) {
                int int1, int2, int3, int4;
                //Need help to write the matcher code
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve every int value, you can use regex:

```
[a-z]+\s(\d+)\s(\d+)\s?(\d+)?\s?(\d+)?
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sI6sP6/1)

and every int will be in groups from 1 to 4. Then you can use somethig like:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] strings = {"foo 11 25","foo 67 45 97",
        "foo 38 15 976 24"};

        for(String string : strings) {
            ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[a-z]+\\s(\\d+)\\s(\\d+)\\s?(\\d+)?\\s?(\\d+)?").matcher(string);
            matcher.find();
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                if(matcher.group(i+1) != null) {
                     numbers.add(Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(i + 1)));
                }else{
                    System.out.println("group " + (i+1) + " is " + matcher.group(i+1));
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Match from string: "+ "\""+ string + "\"" + " : " + numbers.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

with output:

```
group 3 is null
group 4 is null
Match from string: "foo 11 25" : [11, 25]
group 4 is null
Match from string: "foo 67 45 97" : [67, 45, 97]
Match from string: "foo 38 15 976 24" : [38, 15, 976, 24]
```

Another way would be to get all int in one group with:

```
[a-z]+\s((?:\d+\s?)+)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sI6sP6/2)

and split `matcher.group(1)` with space, you will get `String[]` with values. Implementation in Java:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] strings = {"foo 11 25","foo 67 45 97",
        "foo 38 15 976 24"};

        for(String string : strings) {
            ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[a-z]+\\s((?:\\d+\\s?)+)").matcher(string);
            matcher.find();
            String[] nums = matcher.group(1).split("\\s");
            for(String num : nums){
                numbers.add(Integer.valueOf(num));
            }
            System.out.println("Match from string: "+ "\""+ string + "\"" + " : " + numbers.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

with output:

```
Match from string: "foo 11 25" : [11, 25]
Match from string: "foo 67 45 97" : [67, 45, 97]
Match from string: "foo 38 15 976 24" : [38, 15, 976, 24]
```

Comment: @user432209 I updated answer, I added small but complete implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The current regex pattern you are using requires the text `\s\d\s\d` at the end. If you want it to allow for any number of numbers each preceded by whitespace, you would use `(\s+\d+)+`.

So the full regex would be `((?:[a-z][a-z]+)(\s+\d+)+)`